# At what stage of my career should I get certifications?

Tags: career-development, certification

I have been in an administrative support role for approximately 10 months. I've been looking for some options compatible with my area of expertise considering that I'll be graduating in the middle of next year.

My company offers Yellow Belt training for leader positions, but not always, so I've been considering studying for an ASQ CSSYB certification. Although this certification can be an additional in a position that does not require it, I fear that I may get stuck when applicating for jobs where it is considered, but the leadership experience is more important.

Is it a mistake to certify for something that is not highly relevant to my current career moment?

Comment: You should always be working *smartly* towards your long term goals.  Getting certifications takes time and money, and if the value of the certificates isn't worth the cost ...

Answer (score 3):

Certifications are always worth having so long as they're not the ones that need to be renewed. These are better getting when needed unless you have a chance to get it paid for.

Careers can be fluid, plans can change, so the more options open to you and the more you have behind you the better.

Answer (score 1):

A certification is always a good thing to have. I've never heard of an employer saying, "We were thinking of hiring this person, but then we discovered that he has a certification in X."

If a certification is only loosely related to a job you're applying for, it may not be worth a lot, but it should still be worth something. If nothing else it tells the employer that you're smart enough and hard-working enough to get a certification.

I suppose if you had a certification in something totally unrelated to a job you're applying for, an employer might conclude that you're just applying for this job to park here temporarily while you look for the job you really want. Like if you have a certification in software development and you're applying for a job as a waiter, they might well conclude that you will be quitting once you get a software job.

But if some case where the certification would be a negative does come up, just don't mention it. I can't imagine an employer is going to track down irrelevant certifications that you may have. If they ask about certifications, just say "nothing relevant".

The only reason I see to NOT get a certification is because it's too much work or costs too much money and you don't think it will be worth the effort. I've only ever gotten one certification, and I don't know that it was ever a non-trivial factor in getting a job. No one ever mentioned it in an interview. Maybe it was worth a point or two when potential employers were looking over my resume.

I understand that in some field, though, certifications carry a lot of weight.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is that, as you advance in your career, what's expected of you changes in this pattern:

**Attitude -> Knowledge -> Experience -> Accomplishments -> Results ($)**

All of these are always important, but each next step adds expectations further down this line.

Certifications prove knowledge. In some cases, they can also be indicators of experience. As soon as your career advances to the knowledge worker stage, the value of certifications is at its highest. It will remain high until and into the line manager role.

For people who choose to grow as experts, this value stays high forever.

For people who choose to grow as managers, the focus shifts from knowledge to experience, then accomplishments, and finally financial results. For instance, I don't even list certifications by name in my CV - just a rough total count. The investors are looking for proof of having turned $X into $X*k where k>>1. Skills are fading into the background as an explanation for how I did it.